# Can't convert reader.ReadString() to string

Tags: c#, xmlreader

*Language* C# *in Forms*.

I'm trying to change a label to some xml data that I retrieved, but it I get the error that it can't convert it to a string. It's confusing since im reading it as a string?

I already tried it out in a console project, it works fine there:

**Code in Console :**

```
String URLString = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?...

XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);

reader.ReadStartElement("Bid");
Console.Write("YAHOO's current bid price: ");
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
reader.ReadEndElement();
```

**Code in Forms:**

```
String URLString = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?...

XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);

reader.ReadToFollowing("Bid");
reader.ReadStartElement("Bid");
lblBidPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.ReadString());
reader.ReadEndElement();
```

Comment: There are difference between two snippets you have provided.

Comment: Your code is different in both examples... I would assume the problem is in `reader.ReadToFollowing("Bid")` since it is missing from your Console program.  Can you post the exact error and what line it is generated from please?

Comment: The code works fine if there is a `<Bid>` element in XML. Post the sample XML you're trying to parse.

Comment: The Original Poster said, "I get the error that it can't convert it to a string". What is "it" and what, exactly, is the error you're getting? We need a problem statement to help you.

Comment: This `Convert.ToString(reader.ReadString());` definitely makes no sencse. `reader.ReadString` already returns string.

Comment: The problem solved it self after some restarts of Visual Studio, makes no sense no changes to the code was needed. Thanks any way, extremly good response.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<Bid>
  This is bid content
</Bid>
" ;
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml) ;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr) ;
reader.MoveToContent() ;
reader.ReadStartElement("Bid");
string content = Convert.ToString(reader.ReadString()) ;
Console.WriteLine( content ) ;
reader.ReadEndElement();
```

producing the output you'd expect (though why you'd feel a need to try to convert a string to a string is beyond me):

```
  This is bid content
```

with the additional leading/trailing linebreaks you'd expect.

Comment: It worked fine for me too but I'm not sure if that can be an asnwer. I think we're missing some information from the asker here.